# Generalization arrows

Tags: oop, uml

Do generalization arrows in class diagram has to be strictly open or is there a margin of tolerance on style of this arrows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open arrows are used together with a dashed/dotted line to represent dependencies.

I can't think of a standard way to use them with a regular line.

Furthermore, as Martin Fowler clearly indicates in [UML Distilled](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020165783X), UML is just a  notation. If the people that will read your diagrams are aware that `open arrow = closed arrow`, then feel free to use it. There is no *strictness* in UML.

Answer (score 1):

Each element in UML has to strictly follow the normative notation proposed in the standard. With so many symbols there is a high risk that a notation variant for a symbol coincides with the normative representation of another one

Answer (score 0):

Talking about UML designs without an image is like talking about girl without ...... :-)
Here is the picture of UML2 connectors in the class diagram:

[alt text http://www.forum-omondo.com/documentation_eclipseuml_2008/connectors_uml2.png](http://www.forum-omondo.com/documentation_eclipseuml_2008/connectors_uml2.png)